# Transition doesn't work after insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: css

my css is this:

```js
function showNoResults() {
  results.innerHTML = ''
  results.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'afterbegin',
    `<div class='no-results'>
          <h1 style="transform: translateX(0);">No results found :(</h1>
         </div>`
  )
}
```

```css
.no-results h1 {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>

<button onclick="showNoResults()">showNoResults</button>
```

Text shows up but without transition

Comment: transition wont work if there is no content. as of now you are including HTML later after the CSS and Js are compiled then adds the HTML since the CSS has run one time and not found the class it wont look again for class and the transition doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommand using animations, as long as animation starts when the element is added to the dom. Then, you can dynamically append elements that have this animation, and the animation will run.

You can find an example of what I just explained : https://jsfiddle.net/w6kqscgn/

```
p {
  animation: appear 2s;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from { 
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert the element then change the transform property to trigger the transition. You should do this after a slight delay that's why I used setTimeout:

```js
function showNoResults() {
  results.innerHTML = ''
  results.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'afterbegin',
    `<div class='no-results'>
          <h1 >No results found :(</h1>
         </div>`
  )
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.no-results h1').style.transform="translateX(0)";
  },1);
}
```

```css
.no-results h1 {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>

<button onclick="showNoResults()">showNoResults</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A diferent approach would be to trigger the animation with another class:

```
.no-results h1 {
   transform: translateX(0);
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.no-results.active h1 {
   transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Insert the element in the HTML document:

```
showNoResults() {
  this.cache.results.innerHTML = ''
  this.cache.results.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'afterbegin',
    `<div id="noresults" class='no-results'>
      <h1>No results found :(</h1>
     </div>`
  )
}
```

To trigger animation, just add the class to the `div` element when you want:

```
document.getElementById("noresults").classList.add("active");
```